# Can I use a constexpr function to run an algorithm on an array at compile time?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constexpr

I have an array like this one below:

```
std::array<char, 10> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

I have to add 2 more bytes that would represent the checksum of the array.
The checksum is calculated like this:

```
char x = 0;
char y = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    x = x + array[i];
    y = x + y;
}
```

Finally, the values `x` and `y` should be added at the end array.

I want the array to be `static` inside a method of a class. I don't know if that matters.

```
class Foo
{
 public:
  char * getData(void)
  {
    static std::array<char, 10> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    // checksum must be calculated here.
    return &numbers[0];
  }
}
```

If I leave two extra bytes space in the array and pass it by reference in a `constexpr` function. Would that work?

```
constexpr void checksum_calc(std::array<char, 12>& arr)
{
  char x = 0;
  char y = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 12 - 2; i++)
  {
      x = x + array[i];
      y = x + y;
  }
  arr[10] = x;
  arr[11] = y;
}
```

Also, if I want the array to work on different sizes, can I make it a template?
Like this?

```
template <size_t sz>
constexpr void checksum_calc(std::array<char, sz>& arr)
{
  char x = 0;
  char y = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < sz - 2; i++)
  {
      x = x + array[i];
      y = x + y;
  }
  arr[sz - 2] = x;
  arr[sz - 1] = y;
}
```

Example:

```
char * getData()
{
  // two extra bytes for the checksum
  static std::array<char, 12> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  checksum_calc<12>(numbers);
  return &numbers[0];
}
```

The reason I chose a template is because I want arrays of different sizes like:

Example 2:

```
char * foo_getData()
{
  // two extra bytes for the checksum
  static std::array<char, 7> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  checksum_calc<7>(numbers);
  return &numbers[0];
}

char * bar_getData()
{
  // two extra bytes for the checksum
  static std::array<char, 9> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  checksum_calc<9>(numbers);
  return &numbers[0];
}
```

The purpose is to have a constant array followed by 2 bytes checksum that must be calculated.
I don't want to calculate it by hand and add it.

Is what I'm trying to do a good practice?

Comment: If your `numbers` array is constexpr, you can create another constexpr like `numbers_with_chksum`with the checksum but you can't just change the size of a `std::array` after the fact whether constexpr or not.

Comment: Please clarify Your intent is to use `static std::array<char, 12> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0};` or similar with 2 extra entries for the checksum in place of `static std::array<char, 10> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};`?

Comment: @doug Will I end up having only one array in the code at the end?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, and calculate the checksum using a `constexpr` function at compile time. I want to populate the 2 last positions of the array at compile time, since all bytes are known. Can I do that?

Comment: Playing with compiler explorer shows that, yes, it will happen at compile time, see: https://godbolt.org/z/5M8znznxe There array was optimized out completly. BUT, its not a requirement for `constexpr` functions to be executed at compile time, they merely *may* be executed at compile time if they called not in constant expression, so in complex situations they can be executed at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, if you want to create `constexpr` arrays and have C++17 you can do following:

```
template <size_t sz>
constexpr std::array<char, sz+2> checksum_calc(const std::array<char, sz>& arr)
{
  std::array<char, sz+2> res = {};
  char x = 0;
  char y = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
  {
      res[i] = arr[i];
      x = x + arr[i];
      y = x + y;
  }
  res[sz] = x;
  res[sz+1] = y;
  return res;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
constexpr array<char, 1> a1 = {1};
constexpr auto a2 = checksum_calc(a1);

//or

constexpr auto a3 = checksum_calc<1>({2});
```

Comment: Will I end up having only one array at the end? Can the compiler optimize out the first array and leave me with the desired result? Because I wouldn't like spending memory and keep both arrays

Comment: Yes, it may even optimize out second array too, this depend on its usage.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need checksum_calc to be separated? Otherwise, you can play more with C++17 capabilities and group your array and checksum compute together:
https://godbolt.org/z/TW8EEG7Ej

```
template<typename _Ty, std::size_t _N>class checksumed_array {
  std::array<_Ty, _N + 2> _data;

  constexpr void compute_checksum() noexcept {
    char x = 0;
    char y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _N; i++) {
      x = x + _data[i];
      y = x + y;
    }
    _data[_N] = x;
    _data[_N+1] = y;
  }
public:
  template<typename... _TyInt>
  constexpr checksumed_array(_TyInt... vals) noexcept : _data{ ((_Ty)vals)... } {
    compute_checksum();
  }

  constexpr const _Ty& operator[](std::size_t i) const noexcept {
    return _data[i];
  }

  constexpr operator const std::array<_Ty, _N + 2>& () const noexcept {
    return _data;
  }
};
```

Thanks to this, everything is static and can probably be better optimized away. Warning: operator[] and cast should be done without const context for this class to operate at runtime.

Use example :

```
constexpr checksumed_array<int, 3> ca = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::cout << ca[2] << " " << ca[3] << " " << ca[4] << "\n";
```

[Edit 1] Fixed missing const attributes for operator[] and cast... Thanks @doug from comments !

Comment: constexpr functions can be evaluated at runtime or compile time. Your example is runtime. OP asked for compile time. To force an attempt at compile time use: `constexpr checksumed_array<int, 3> ca = { 1, 2, 3 };` It fails. Nice coding, btw. but you need to read up more on constexpr.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I was only looking at disassembled output and as clang -O3 was able to optimize the code anyway I didn't see the mistake. Updated

Comment: Looks good to go.